# Door-to-Wall Relationship Words

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a useful word for the relationship of a door to a door which is "in" the same wall?

The best way I can think of to describe it is "the wall containing the door", but "containing" sounds very odd.

For example, I want to say "Two beds lie against the wall containing the door." How can I say this without using "containing"?

Comment: Sometimes you just use words to describe what you mean.

Comment: "[another|the other] door in the same wall" is absolutely fine. I cannot think of any other phrasing which is less clumsy.

Comment: To avoid "containing" in your example sentence, you could say "Two beds lie against the wall that has the door."

Comment: I'd say: "two beds lie against the wall with the/a door"

Comment: The wall surrounding the door.  The wall that encompasses the door.  The wall adjacent to the door.  The wall bordering the door.  The wall which includes the door.  The wall embracing the door.

Comment: Or you can simply move the beds to the other side and say "The wall opposite the door."

Comment: @HotLicks - moving the beds would make things easier...you are just right !!:))

Comment: One thing I've learned as a writer is that, in situations like this, nobody much cares to know exactly which wall contains the door. If you say "Two beds lie against the wall a ways from the door" no reader will ask you to be more precise. Indeed, further precision will only call attention to unimportant detail at the expense of more significant matters, which I presume you are going to get around to once you have dispensed with the room's layout.

Comment: @Robusto I'm not writing for a reader; I'm writing a scene description for a script, in which the layout of the room goes on to play an important role.

Comment: Then don't be so fussy about using more language for your description.

Comment: I would just say 'two beds lie against the bedroom entrance'.  The reader will infer there is a wall there.

Comment: What about "the door's wall"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to avoid the usage of the word *containing*, you could use one of the following:

> Two beds lie against the wall holding the door.
>   Two beds lie against the wall punctured by the door.
>   Against the wall, two beds lie adjacent to the door.
>   Two beds face the wall across from the door.
>   Two beds lie against the door's wall.
>   Two beds and a door share a wall.

The choice will depend heavily upon your writing style and the mood you wish to set for the reader.

When writing prop directions within a script, you will need even more clarity if the position of the beds is really that important. Writing that the beds simply *lie against the wall* tells me nothing about which end of the bed touches the wall; perhaps it's the side of the bed?

> The room has two beds. The heads of these beds are flush against the door's wall. They are both on one side of the door. They are on opposite sides of the door. Their feet are attached to the ceiling.